# blender image showing transparent on cube

Tags: rendering, texturing, image

[image: transparent cube]

As I place an image texture onto a cube, the cube renders transparent, you know those black & white checkerboards.

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Please add at least one screenshot to better illustrate the issue.

Comment: please check the edited post

Comment: Hello :). This can be caused by many, many things. Please add an image of your material and maybe [share your .blend](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).